# how to make the TreeView backcolor transparent?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, treeview

im trying to place treeview on UserControl and when im trying to set the TreeView backcolor to transparent i got error, there is another way to do it ?

thanks in advance,

shachar.

Comment: I tried it and I got a notification that the `TreeView` doesn't support `Transparent`...not really an error,

Answer (score 0):

`TreeView` does not support transparent background color.  You're best option is to just set the background color of the `TreeView` to that of the `TreeView`'s parent container.

Handle the `BackColorChanged` event on the UserControl and set the `TreeView` bg color to the TreeView bg color in the event handler.

```
    private void treeViewParent_BackColorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           treeView1.BackColor = treeViewParent.BackColor;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing called transparent background for a windows treeview control. But you can play around with some method like OnPaint or OnPaintBackground. This link could help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1e430ef4(vs.71).aspx#Y798